# Why different UIs display different size of the same file?

Tags: files, osx, size

Here's what Finder displays:

[image]

QuickTime 7:

[image]

Terminal:

[image]

Why?

Comment: Don't use the -h flag with ls and you'll get the file size in bytes. You can calculate the result there by whatever measure you prefer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These are basically two different calculations of "M" (megabytes or mebibytes)

The SI prefix "mega" means 10^6, which seems to be what Finder uses. The actual file size of your example is somewhere around 360,400,000 bytes.

However, in computing it's also common to use the binary prefix "mebi" which is 2^20 (1048576). If you take 360,400,000 and divide by 2^20, you get 343.7, which rounds up to the 344M you see in the terminal.

Neither prefix is "correct" (although some will argue otherwise), and unfortunately some programs use ambiguous "M" suffix instead of "MB" or "MiB". Some programs allow for configuration to use either prefix.

Your QuickTime example is different still. The column there says "Data Size", which is not the same as file size, since there is extra overhead information in your media files.

Comment: What about 342.35 MB shown in QT7 though? :D

Comment: Sorry, missed that! Just added a paragraph about it, but basically the "Data Size" shown there will be smaller than the file size due to extra overhead info within the file.